# Javascript - loop is making onclick event happen without the "click"

Tags: javascript

So I have this piece of code:

```
window.onload = function () {make_buttons ('calc'); }

function make_buttons (id) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = 'text';
    input.id = 'inp';
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(input);
    for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
        var btn = document.createElement ("button");
        btn.id = i;
        var txt = document.createTextNode (i);
        btn.appendChild(txt);
        var make_btn = document.getElementById(id).appendChild(btn);
        make_btn.onclick = document.getElementById("inp").value += i;
    }
};
```

So when I load the page, all the numbers from 1 to 9 are printed into my text field.  But adding a number in the text field should only happen when I click it because of the onclick thing.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: The `onclick` property should be a function. You're executing `document.getElementById("inp").value += i` and setting `onclick` to be the result of that expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple problems:

1. You must assign a function reference to `onclick` not just a statement (using an event listener would be even better).
2. Your loop variable will not be the proper value without wrapping it in a closure because your `for` loop has run to completion BEFORE the event handler is actually executed.

You can change it to this:

```
function make_buttons (id) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(id);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = 'text';
    input.id = 'inp';
    parent.appendChild(input);
    for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
        var btn = document.createElement ("button");
        btn.innerHTML = i;
        btn.id = i;
        parent.appendChild(btn);
        // wrap in a closure created by an 
        // IIEF (immediately invoked function expression) to capture 
        // the value of i uniquely for each event handler
        (function(index) {
            btn.onclick = function() {
                input.value += index;
            }
        })(i);
    }
};
```

See [this reference](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) for more info on the IIFE.

FYI, summary of fixes and simplifications:

1. Fetches `document.getElementById(id)` just once and saves the result in a variable.
2. Uses `btn.innerHTML` instead of creating a text node.
3. Uses `btn` instead of creating a new variable `make_btn`.
4. Uses the `input` variable in the event handler instead of finding it again.
5. Creates the IIEF (immediately invoked function expression) to capture the value of `i` separately for each event handler so they don't all have the same value `i` has at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: Allright it is working now but I still don't understand the (function part of the code. Am not really familiar with such things yet.

Comment: @Veske - it just creates a function that is immediately run.  And, when it's run, it passes the current value of `i` into the function - see the `(i)` at the end of it.  This makes the then current value of `i` a function argument (I named the argument `index` to distinguish it) which will be uniquely different for each event handler.  This is a common problem when creating event handlers in a `for` loop when the event handler wants to use the `for` index value.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. It was a lot of help!

Comment: @Veske - see [this reference](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) for more info on the IIFE.

Answer (score 1):

```
make_btn.addEventListener("click", (function(i){
    return function(){
        document.getElementById("inp").value += i;
    };
})(i));
```

Comment: Giving unexpected end of input error for some reason.

Comment: @Veske - Then you must did something wrong elsewhere in your code.